# django-ckeditor render full widget instead my custom widget

Tags: javascript, django, django-ckeditor

I define some custom widgets in my settings for user with ckeditor. In one page I try use this custom template and it dont show me a custom widget, it is displayed with full widget.

In this case, I use one form that cames from ajax request.

My model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=settings.COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT if hasattr(settings, "COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT") else 10000)
```

My form:

```
class CreateCommentForm(IdeiaForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
    max_length=settings.COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT if hasattr(settings,     "COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT") else 10000,
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'data-config': json_encode(getattr(settings, 'CKEDITOR_CONFIGS', None)['comment'])}))
```

and my HTML file:

```
<textarea id="text_area_content" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Deixe seu comentário" data-url-login="{% url 'account:is_logged' %}" data-trigger="login" data-token="{{ csrf_token }}"></textarea>
```

My settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
    'comment': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic'],
            ['CodeSnippet'],
        ],
        'entities': False,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'autolink', 'dialog',
            'codesnippet','autogrow','placeholder',
    ]),
},
```

}

Comment: Another unrelated note in the same fashion:

This line: `json_encode(getattr(settings, 'CKEDITOR_CONFIGS', None)['comment']` will raise a `KeyError` if `'CKEDITOR_CONFIGS'` is undefined

It should probably be `json_encode(getattr(settings, 'CKEDITOR_CONFIGS', {}).get('comment')` instead

Comment: What do you mean "a form that comes from AJAX request" perhaps attach your view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the HTML file you're speaking of is a Django template.

It seems you are not actually using the textarea you've defined in the form. So the custom `data-config` attribute is not used.

If you have access to the form in the template you should use `{{ form.text_area_content }}` to render the field you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, the documentation mentions you can reference your *custom CKEditor settings* either in `RichTextField` or e.g when using a `CKEditorWidget`:

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget


class CreateCommentForm(IdeiaForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        max_length=getattr(settings, "COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT", 10000),
        required=True,widget=CKEditorWidget(config_name='comment')
    )
```

You then have to make sure you render the form using template tags (as in @jaap3's answer), updating the docs example, and assuming you're passing the form to the view as `form = CreateCommentForm()`:

```
<form>
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```